# How do I invoke a google cloud function through HTTPS request using a SIM800

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, arduino, google-cloud-functions, sim800

I have an express app running on firebase functions. I have tested invoking the function from my browser to write data to my database and it works perfectly fine. I also set the "Cloud Functions Invoker" permission to "allUsers".

My problem is, I need to send sensor data collected on an Arduino UNO to my cloud firestore through a SIM800 GPRS module (Making an HTTP request to my firebase function). I have tried AT+HTTPSSL=1 to enable SSL, but when sending the request I get a 606 response, which means "SSL alert message with a level of fatal result in the immediate termination of the connection" according to the [SIM800 Series_SSL_Application Note_V1.01](http://www.microchip.ua/simcom/SIM800x/Application%20Notes/SIM800%20Series_SSL_Application%20Note_V1.01.pdf) documentation.

I have tried sending requests to an HTTP server hosting a PHP script and it worked fine, and from there I am able to use curl to do an HTTPS request to my firebase function, and it works fine, but it takes minutes to refresh my database, which is undesired.

Please let me know if there is a way to invoke a Google cloud function using the mentioned hardware. If not, what would you do in my situation?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi @VictorManuel welcome to Stackoverflow Community! Could you please check this [repository](https://github.com/jawher-Mansour/GPRS-Firebase)? It seems it was developed to allow the usage of SIM800 modules with Firebase directly, which could impact the refresh time from your database.

Comment: Unfotunately that repo uploads to the real time database. What I am trying to do is uploading my data to Cloud Firestore (which is different from the firebase real time db)

Comment: Besides, it does not work

Comment: Hi @VictorManuel Thanks for the information! Considering the fact that you said it doesn't work, could you please clarify what doesn't work? Since you mentioned that it was not useful for your case, I'm in doubt on why it doesn't work. Besides that, I would recommend you to reach out to [Firestore Free Support](https://firebase.google.com/support), so they can assist you and confirm if there is any other possibility.